# Is there a GUI for remapping the keyboard in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

Is there a GUI for remapping the keyboard in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS? For example, I want to swap <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>win</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd> keys to <kbd>win</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> respectively. I've managed that with `xmodmap` but it's error-prone and complex. Since I'd like to change another couple things I was looking for a simpler workflow.

A search seems to point to gnome-tweaks or system settings, but they seem changed compared to - for example - 18.04 and I cannot find a keyboard-mapping section in either.

I'd like to avoid having to change things in xkb - seems a bit too complex and risky.

Comment: Please edit your question and ask something specific.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarssonn- done

Comment: Not good enough. The tools you mention (Tweaks and Settings) include GUIs for some kind of keyboard configuration. What do you mean by "remapping the keyboard"?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson for example, swap ctr win and alt keys to win alt and ctrl respectively. I've managed that with xmodmap but it's error-prone and complex. Since I'd like to change another couple things I was looking for a simpler workflow.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson: “Remapping the keyboard” is a very normal thing to say, and means mapping the hardware’s keycodes to certain keysyms. So this is really only your problem and you’re not the judge to tell people what is good enough anyway. So please apply common sense and refrain from treating people this way in the future.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me as if you want to explore *Tweaks -> Keyboard & Mouse -> Additional Layout Options*.

To get an overview of available XKB options, you may want to run

```
man xkeyboard-config
```

and scroll downwards to `OPTIONS`.

Comment: I have been trying all the "xev" and "xmodmap -e" commands and haven't achieved anything. Based on your answer, i just went straight to tweaks and in less in 1min I solved my problem. Sometimes we overcomplicate things

Answer (score 3):

You may be intersted in the Kay-mapper gui

https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/12/remap-keyboard-and-mouse-buttons-on.html

Comment: this is undoubtedly the best solution